# XDebug could not connect to client

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I am trying to debug with NetBeans Mac locally.

This is my php.ini

```
[xdebug]
 xdebug.default_enable=1
 xdebug.remote_enable=1
 xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
 xdebug.remote_host=localhost
 xdebug.remote_port=9000
 xdebug.remote_autostart=1
 xdebug.remote_log="/Applications/MAMP/logs/xdebug.log"
 xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
 zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so"
```

This is what I had been getting in xdebug.log

```
  I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000.
   E: Could not connect to client. :-(
```

I try changing the port to 9001 and turn off firewall and it didn't help.

Comment: Sometimes it does not work if you have same xdebug server in use for multiple IDEs

Comment: How do I check if I have multiple xdebug server?

Comment: You dont have multiple xdebug server.  I am talking about one server but multiple IDE connection

Comment: I don't. It is working now.

Answer (score 12):

Xdebug's default port (9000) conflicts with FastCGI (Xdebug was first!) - the solution is to change it to another port. After having done that, you need to restart your IDE where you will also need to configure the new port. You will also need to restart PHP and your Web Server.

Comment: Man... I have done a bunch of things but didn't close my IDE (Sublime Text) and didn't configure port in my IDE either... thank you very much! (And I'm saying this after so many searches)

Comment: So many thankis, this solved the problem also for me (Windows 10, Netbenas, PHP 7.2 from XAMPP), using Postman.

Answer (score 8):

Step 1:
Change `xdebug.remote_port=9000` to `xdebug.remote_port=9001`

Step 2:

1. Change the debugging port in Netbeans. Go to Tools >> Options >> Click PHP tab
2. Under PHP tab click debugging
3. Change the debugger port : 9001
4. Change Session ID : netbeans-xdebug

Step 3:
Restart server and netbeans

Step 4:
Set a breakpoint and try

Comment: Step 2: has four sub-steps....sorry it didnt create a newline so happen to be one line

Answer (score 6):

I had exact the same problem.
The xdebug installion wizard (https://xdebug.org/wizard.php) showed that my xdebug was correctly installed. (The wizard told me to install the Xdebug 2.5.0rc1 dll)
In phpinfo I also got a xdebug section showing (in my opinion) the correct values. Even with this I got a "could not connect to client" message in the error log.

Eventually I solved it by trial and error doing the following:
Downloaded all the older versions of the xdebug dll's for my php version and tried them all. Eventually one of them worked. For me it was with php 5.6.8 the xdebug 2.4.1 dll (PHP 5.6 VC11 TS (32 bit) ) on a windows 7 32 bit machine. I am using xampp-win32-5.6.8-0-VC11.zip for my xampp installation.

What I learned was the following:
(a) The Xdebug wizard does not neccesarily give the correct dll to use
(b) Even though phpinfo shows a Xdebug section with correct variables this does not necessarily mean that it is correct.
(c) Try older versions of the dll's if you get this error.

Comment: This worked for me. Also, despite being on a 64 bit machine, it was the 32 bit version that worked for me :)

Comment: This worked for me too. i found php_xdebug-2.6.0rc2-7.2-ts-vc15-x64 works well with PHP7.2.24
DON"T waste time with other Xdebug Versions for PHP7.2.24 :)