# PHP XDebug on Docker Containers do not works in VS Code (Laravel and docker-compose)

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, xdebug

I cannot manage to run php debugger in my docker-compose containers environment using visual studio code and Xdebug.

I try all the steps in this [article](https://medium.com/@afrimadonidinata/configure-remote-debugging-with-xdebug-on-visual-studio-code-using-docker-for-mac-10528eadf832) and various questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033605/xdebug-could-not-connect-to-client) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43360282/docker-and-xdebug-not-reading-breakpoints-vscode/43365142#43365142) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52579102/debug-php-with-vscode-and-docker)

I have this `docker-compose.yml` file (php conatainer section):

```
version: '2'
services:
    php:
        build: 
            context: images/php
        ports: 
            - "9000:9000"
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www
        links:
            - mysql
        depends_on: 
            - mysql
        network_mode: "bridge"
```

The `./www` volume is my Laravel root application path, mounted to the `php` container:

[image]

This is the `php` Dockerfile section where I install Xdebug:

```
RUN yes | pecl install xdebug \
    && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.default_enable=1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_enable=1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_connect_back=1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_autostart=1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_port=9000' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_host=0.0.0.0' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.max_nesting_level=250' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_log=/var/www/xdebug.log' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
```

When I build my containers I have no errors, and attaching a shell to php container and running `php -v` I have this output:

```
PHP 7.2.3 (cli) (built: Mar 22 2018 22:03:09) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

So, Xdebug is intalled into the container. I installed PHP-debug extension and set this VSCode debug configuration:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
        "name": "Listen for XDebug on Docker",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000,
        "pathMappings": {
            "/var/www": "${workspaceFolder}/www",
        },
        "log": true,
        "ignore": [
            "**/vendor/**/*.php"
        ]
    }]
}
```

The app is working, I set a breakpoint to `www/public/index.php` at this line

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

and start to debug. I have a debug console output:

```
<- launchResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 2,
  command: 'launch',
  success: true }
```

When I refresh the app in my browser I have two new logs in my laravel root into the file `./www/xdebug.log`:

```
Log opened at 2019-01-13 13:29:35
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 172.17.0.1:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/public/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.2.3" protocol_version="1.0" appid="6" idekey="user"><engine version="2.6.1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2018 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2019-01-13 13:29:36

Log opened at 2019-01-13 13:51:23
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 172.17.0.1:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/public/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.2.3" protocol_version="1.0" appid="7" idekey="user"><engine version="2.6.1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2018 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2019-01-13 13:51:24
```

But the debugger do not stops to my breakpoint. I tried changing xdebug parameters and vscode configuration many times, but I cannot solve the problem.

Please help me, I've run out of ideas...

Comment: Use another port for Xdebug communication (e.g. `9001` is a typical number). Right now Xdebug might be connecting to php-fpm (uses 9000 port as well by default) or to the wrong IP/service. Once done -- update your config in your question with new port number -- maybe you also doing something else wrong as well.

Comment: sorry, but even if I cahnge the port, it doesn't work: I have already in use at the 9001 too

Comment: Same setup with same problem; spent too much time already trying to get this to work. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured this out myself and thought I would post it in case it helps solve problem for others

As far as I understand the remote_host should be set to 'host.docker.internal'

I've set this in my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  phpapp:
    image: phpapp
    container_name: phpapp
    environment: 
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_port=9050 remote_enable=1 remote_autostart=1
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - 'c:/dev/www:/var/www/html'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since xdebug version 3 there are breaking changes in config names.

Change dockerfile:

```
RUN yes | pecl install xdebug \
    && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.mode=debug' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.start_with_request=yes' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.client_port=9050' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
```

Change port also in vsc config `"port": 9050,`

btw you don't need to expose 9000 or 9050 port