# Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I would like to try Xdebug 3.0.0RC1 to explore what has changed and the new features that come with it. I am also using the latest PhpStorm 2020.3 EAP which supports Xdebug 3 with no major config needed. Below is my PhpStorm config for the Debugger:

[image]

And here is the configuration I have tried for Xdebug3:

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal # here I tried several combinations like: "localhost", "127.0.0.1", "172.17.0.1"
xdebug.client_port=9001 # here I tried several ports 9003 included with no success
```

I have also tried not adding the `client_host/client_port` setting at all and still failing.

I am getting this error:

```
Script php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata returned with error code 255
!!  [17-Nov-2020 15:24:40 UTC] Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9001 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
!!  [17-Nov-2020 15:24:41 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Method class@anonymous::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\AutowiringFailedException:  in /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/AutowirePass.php on line 233
```

Some info about my environment:

- Fedora 33
- Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d
- PhpStorm 2020.3 EAP Build #PS-203.5784.36

It is curious (because apparently `host.docker.internal` is "not" supported by the Docker version I am using and yet it works) and weird at the same time that the following configuration does work with Xdebug 2 even having the debugger listening for incoming connections all the time:

[image]

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

What I am missing here?

Note: I already applied the solution provided by the Xdebug developer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17259423/719427).

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: @LazyOne it's Fedora 33 I have added such info to the OP

Comment: `host.docker.internal` is NOT supported on Linux -- only Windows and Mac -- https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264 . It will be supported since Docker v20 -- https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264#issuecomment-714253414 . If you want to use that host name, your would need to detect the IP address dynamically (the aforementioned link has many options on how to achieve that).

Comment: For now I suggest replacing "host.docker.internal" with the IP address of the machine where PhpStorm is running, which is accessible from the Docker container

Comment: Try `xdebug.discover_client_host = true` Xdebug 3 option -- may work.

Comment: @LazyOne `host.docker.internal` has been working for me with `Xdebug 2` til early today when I decided to give a try to Xdebug 3, weird

Comment: @ReynierPM You may have that other option in place (e.g. `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1` -- Xdebug 2 equivalent of Xdebug's 3 `xdebug.discover_client_host = true`). Use explicit IP address (hardcode it) .. or detect it dynamically.

Comment: @LazyOne it didn't work either :( `Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 10.211.55.12:9001`

Comment: @ReynierPM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944631/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container -- run through those recipes and confirm what IP address of the host actually is in your running container. Then try to use that IP address in php.ini.

Comment: @ReynierPM Another option: temporarily revert back to Xdebug 2 (in the same container) and see what IP address it uses -- the same/similar (as it may change) or a completely different? If Xdebug log shows only host name -- try resolving it to the IP address (inside the container, of course).

Comment: At this moment the wrong IP address is the main suspect (assuming that EVERYTHING else is the same .. so it's unlikely to be a Firewall issue or alike). P.S. But you may also check if it's PhpStorm that listens on 9001 port on your host OS (using `netstat` or alike) while "phone handle" icon in PhpStorm is green (IDE is listening for the incoming Xdebug requests).

Comment: @LazyOne https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264#issuecomment-714253414 is really old and as per today `host.docker.internal` is supported that issue is really old but either way I always have that `phone handle` green. Disabling it I was able to get the stack up & running however I am seeing this error now in `docker logs`: `[17-Nov-2020 16:32:42 UTC] Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 127.0.0.1:7777 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header), 10.211.55.1:7777 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(`

Comment: 26 days old comment is REALLY OLD? The comment says "host.docker.internal is already supported in **Docker 20.10-beta1:**" -- your Docker is v19... Maybe they have backported is already -- don't know. Anyway -- it says port `7777` is used. Is that the right port?

Comment: Yes, that port is correct I have changed `xdebug.client_port=7777` to something else just in case :(

Comment: Does Xdebug 2 works? Does local debug works (when running PHP on host OS and not inside the container)?

Comment: @LazyOne I do not have PHP nor Xdebug outside of the container so not sure whether they work or not :| and yes Xdebug 2 does work. I will add some info about Xdebug 2 in the OP

Comment: What IP `host.docker.internal` resolves to (inside the container)? We can try TeamViewer session? I may spot something with my eyes in the process/watching you/IDE settings.

Comment: I am open to try Teamviewer just write me over PM to send you a pic of my setup for it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224686/discussion-between-lazyone-and-reynierpm).

Comment: Just spent the entire night working on this. Turns out ufw was enabled and it was blocking the port. `ufw allow 9003` fixed this, but should probably lock it down by IP/device

Comment: @Farkie thank you so much, had the same problem, your comment saved me. `sudo ufw status verbose`, `sudo ufw disable` to check it was ufw blocking the port, and `sudo ufw enable` + `sudo ufw allow 9003` to definitely resolve the pb. Didn't even know I had ufw installed!

Comment: @scandel good job I came back to answer!

Comment: This happens to me since I switched to rootless docker. Seems like a dead end.

Answer (score 55):

PHP 7.4 
Docker 
PHPStorm 2020.1 
Xdebug 3.1.0

Install Xdebug in your docker container using Dockerfile

```
RUN pecl install xdebug-3.0.1 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

Configure php.ini with following:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.discover_client_host = 1
```

Go to PHPStorm - Settings - PHP - Debug - Xdebug and set the port to **9003** (by default)

[PHPStorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpIOO.png)

That's it (:

If you want to enable/disable debugger only when you need it: just install a browser extension called "Xdebug helper", select "Debug" and remove "xdebug.start_with_request = yes" from php.ini

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.discover_client_host = 1
```

Comment: I tried this exact configuration, but I still get `Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 172.19.0.1:9003 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header)`

Comment: Adding `xdebug.discover_client_host = 1` and double checking my ports was the solution, thanks!

Comment: Why does this fix the problem?

Answer (score 31):

What worked for me was to change `start_with_request` from **yes** to `trigger`.

This worked for me:

```ini
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
xdebug.client_port=9003
```

**EDIT:**
As pointed out in the comments, the `trigger/9003` are the default settings. If this answer works for you, it means something is overriding the default settings, and by explicitly using `trigger/9003`, you force back to the default settings.

Comment: Note that `xdebug.start_with_request` is automatically set to `trigger` when `xdebug.mode=debug`, so it's not needed to be defined. The `xdebug.client_port=9003` is also the default for Xdebug 3, so that is not needed either. Refs: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#start_with_request https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#client_port

Comment: why does it work?

Comment: @KhayLeng It seems something is overriding the default settings, and by setting `trigger/9003`, you force the settings back to the defaults. I just edited my answer to add this information.

Answer (score 15):

I created a very simple configuration that allows me to use `Xdebug` with any PHP version with minimal effort *(v2: 5.6-7.1, v3: 7.2-8.x)*. All I need to do is configure *PhpStorm* and `docker-compose.yml` in three places and I can debug.

### Configuration:

[gander/dev](https://github.com/gander-tools/docker-dev) @ [xdebug2.ini](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gander-tools/docker-dev/master/config/xdebug2.ini):

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
; https://2.xdebug.org/docs/all_settings
; ------------------------------------
; Enables Step Debugging
xdebug.remote_enable=1
; ------------------------------------
; Address where IDE listening for incoming debugging connections
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
; ------------------------------------
; Port where IDE listening for incoming debugging connections
xdebug.remote_port=9003
; ------------------------------------
; Color var_dumps when in CLI
xdebug.cli_color=1
; ------------------------------------
```

[gander/dev](https://github.com/gander-tools/docker-dev) @ [xdebug3.ini](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gander-tools/docker-dev/master/config/xdebug3.ini):

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
; https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings
; ------------------------------------
; Enables Step Debugging
xdebug.mode=debug,develop
; ------------------------------------
; Address where IDE listening for incoming debugging connections
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
; ------------------------------------
; Port where IDE listening for incoming debugging connections
xdebug.client_port=9003
; ------------------------------------
; Color var_dumps when in CLI
xdebug.cli_color=1
; ------------------------------------
```

[gander/dev](https://github.com/gander-tools/docker-dev) @ [`docker-compose.yml`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gander-tools/docker-dev/master/examples/docker-compose.yml):

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
#...
  dev74:
    hostname: 'dev-74'
    container_name: 'dev_74'
    image: 'gander/dev:7.4'
    volumes:
      - './app/xdebug3:/www/localhost'
    working_dir: '/www/localhost/public'
    ports:
      - '8074:80'
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    environment:
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=dev.74"
#...
```

### Run via CLI:

```bash
XDEBUG_SESSION=1 XDEBUG_CONFIG=1 php script.php
```

or:

```bash
docker-compose exec dev74 bash -c 'XDEBUG_SESSION=1 XDEBUG_CONFIG=1 php index.php'
```

### Side notes:

This `serverName`:

```yaml
PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=dev.74"
```

This is the name of the PhpStorm PHP server (shown in the screenshot below)

### Screenshots:

[image: xdebug port]
[image: configuration]
[image: validation]

---

Here is a list of extensions for various browsers:
[Browser debugging extensions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/browser-debugging-extensions.html)

Comment: Files moved in repo: fixed

Answer (score 8):

PHP 7.3
Docker (for Mac)
PhpStorm 2021.1

---

You may not need to install it via PECL (which took a long time to build and didn't work for me).

All I did was adding `php7.3-xdebug` to my `apt-get install` command and configure the port mapping correctly as follows:

In Dockerfile add:
`RUN apt-get install -y php7.3-xdebug`

In docker-compose.yml I mapped an `extra_host` (this was the secret sauce for me):

```yaml
services:
  web:
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

In php.ini:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal

;optionals: (uncomment if you need them)
;xdebug.start_with_request=yes
;xdebug.discover_client_host=1
```

In PhpStorm I just started listening to port 9003 and configured the server mapping to my needs.

References:

- [XDebug 3 Documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings)
- [Milos Devacic post about xdebug + docker + vscode](https://blog.levacic.net/2020/12/19/xdebug-3-docker-vs-code-setup-guide-on-ubuntu/) (which helped me to find out the extra_host argument)

Comment: I don't think the `extra_hosts` is needed here. That mapping may have been needed at one time (with a linux host). Why did you add it? What is your host OS?

Comment: @marcguyer I'm using MacOs.

Comment: The `host.docker.internal` DNS is automatically set on macOS, so no need for this line.

Answer (score 4):

I will start saying big thanks to @LazyOne who spent some time helping me on this one until we make it to work. Here is how the config looks like for me currently and it is working fine:

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_port=9005
```

You need also to update the Xdebug port at `File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers` to reflect the new one but also enable the option to listen on Xdebug3 incoming connections. (I believe it is enabled by default in PhpStorm 2020.3)

[image]

That is the setup for a backend project where no browser is in the middle, I have not tried but for those, you might need:

```
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
```

And also have `File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers` well configured.

> Note: We found the host had enabled IPv6 and I disabled it and in addition, added the following setting to the IDE through `Help > Edit Custom VM options`: `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`. After added the IP4 setting to the IDE I haven't tried re-enabling IPv6 and see if Xdebug 3 still working

Comment: so what was the issue ? (apart from different port) ?
I mean it looks the same as it is in question and earlier today removing host didn't work either iirc

Comment: @FaizanAkramDar I guess the problem was indeed the host. All I tried today was using it but the latest attempt was without it and it worked. I could revert the IPv6 and see if that cause any issues as well.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to point the attention to the following configuration option in the ini file, because that is what solved the same problem for me.

```
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
```

In PhpStorm's documentation [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html#configuring-xdebug-docker) says that `xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal` has to be configured which seams similar, but is not.

A slight difference is that I use IntelliJ.

Comment: `remote_host` is for Xdebug 2, and `client_host` is for Xdebug 3.

Answer (score 1):

If you have tried all the above answers and still cannot connect to the XDebug server, try to add a new `ALLOW` rule for your Xdebug port (`9003` by default) or turn off your local firewall (**not recommended, but it works**).

Ubuntu and Mint firewall interface is `ufw` and you can allow port 9003 by issuing the following command:

`sudo ufw allow 9003`

Verify the changes with:

`sudo ufw status`

Comment: Running on Linux Mint, I had the same problem. After typing the allow command, I noticed it added a new rule to the firewall software GUI. And now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

For wsl you need to force the client host.

Just open a command prompt:

wsl hostname -I

And this will give the ip:

C:\Users\rapha>wsl hostname -I
172.23.103.149

So them put at you xdebug.ini

xdebug.client_host=172.23.103.149

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I still have it when doing a request from a browser, but from the commandline, like in your case, it now works. What I was missing was a Server configuration with a path mapping. Once it set that up, along with the settings that you already have, it worked. I am on Mac Os Big Sur, using PhpStorm 2020.3

Answer (score 0):

To remove this error displaying in the console. Please mention the log path Xdebug going to use to store the logs. something similar mention below

```
xdebug.log=/var/www/var/log/xdebug.log
```

Comment: I feel like this suppresses the message in the console but doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue if i'm working with the CLI:

```
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 127.0.0.1:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
```

And this is my configuration that causes the warning message:

```
[XDebug]
...
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port = 9003
```

I'm using the config for debugging from the URL, which is using the FPM, and it's working fine.

However, if I'm working with the CLI, then I must change the config, especially the `xdebug.start_with_request`

before (FPM):

> xdebug.start_with_request = yes

after (CLI):

> xdebug.start_with_request = trigger

As an additional information, I'm using Xdebug 3.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error "**Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 127.0.0.1:9001 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).**"
I found that I have to launch the Debugging on the Editor first, then start the web server because when you launch the Debugging on the Editor it will open the port 9001 as you set on the **launch.json** config then Xdebug on PHP can connect to this port.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Docker**.

Solved by editing the auto generated `launch.json` file:

In the config `"name": "Launch Built-in web server"`
Replace any occurrence of `localhost` to the`container`'s name.

In my case:

```
{
  "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
  "type": "php",
  "request": "launch",
  "runtimeArgs": [
    "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
    "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
    "-S",
    "magento:0"
  ],
  "program": "",
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "port": 9003,
  "serverReadyAction": {
    "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://magento:([0-9]+)\\) started",
    "uriFormat": "http://magento:%s",
    "action": "openExternally"
  }
}
```

I replaced all `localhost` with `magento` (the container name).

---

I believe same solution should work for local development (not using Docker) if you are using custom domain name rather than `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

working on ubuntu `php 8.1`
xdebug on `ini`

```
    zend_extension=xdebug
    [xdebug]
    xdebug.mode=develop,debug
    xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
    xdebug.discover_client_host=1
    xdebug.start_with_request=yes
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug on Docker",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html/": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I had same problem ( ubuntu 20.4 - docker 20.10 - xdebug 3)

My solution was:

1. `xdebug.discover_client_host=1`
2. Disable firewall `sudo ufw disable`

Comment: Disabling the Firewall completly can never be a solution